# Lead Conversion issue using update statement!

Tags: apex

I have a un-usual problem,

I am converting a Lead and in After update event when the Lead is converted and entry is made in my Test__c Object.

But before converting the Lead in the same call I am updating a field on the same Lead and after that converting it.

In this case my Lead doesn't get converted but if I don't update my lead and directly convert it it converts without any error.

So where is the problem does the Lead in update events is still locked and thus it cannot be converted??

```
Lead varlead = vNonConvertedLWrp;
varlead.test__c = vRelOppId;
Update varlead;

Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
lc.setLeadId(varlead.id);
//varRelOpp is Opportunity
if(varRelOpp.AccountID != null){
    lc.setAccountId(varRelOpp.AccountID);
}
lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(true);
lc.setSendNotificationEmail(false);
LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];
lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);
Database.LeadConvertResult lcr ;
try{
    lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
    system.debug('*****lcr.isSuccess()'+lcr.isSuccess());
}
catch(exception ex){
    system.debug('***NOT CONVERTED**');
    return null;
}
```

I always get *****lcr.isSuccess() as true.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Can you please rephrase your Q. Can you reorganize what happens when? I tried to figure out which trigger you are using, and/or when the lead is converted correctly, but couldn't from how your Q is written.

Answer (score 1):

The Update Lead will cause another (nested) round of Lead triggers to run. 
So also the conversion will run twice.

This is my guess of what is happening: maybe the first one goes fine (hence the success = true) but the second one doesn't, as the Lead is already converted then, and then the whole transaction is rolled back because of the failed conversion.

I'd advice to do any update to the record itself in the Before trigger and the conversion in the After trigger.